# In WPF, how to set an outer, centered, and inner border?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, border

When I set a border for a button, for example, it is an outer border. But What if I would want it to be centered or inner, what would be the simplest way?

Here is what I mean:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/88ibeiz.jpg]

Comment: Are you just trying to do like the equivalent of a css inset effect? That can be done with one element use DropShadowEffect, but the others would require two as `Border` doesn't support that functionality at the moment.

Comment: I don't think so. Isn't the css inset effect make the border 3D?

Comment: It can if you set the attributes accordingly, I probably should have likened it to more as like box-sizing css wise where the size is determined to include the border or content etc. There's no property like that on Border to allow what you're showing, but if you can display what you're after we could likely provide a simple alternative technique.

Comment: Thank you very much. Hmm... The pic is not clear enough?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So to re-create your example, here's quickie concept example alternatives. However there's a bunch of different ways you can accomplish the same effects but here's at least a few...

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#570000FF"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <Border>
        <Rectangle/>
    </Border>

    <Border>
        <Rectangle Margin="-5"/>
    </Border>

    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Rectangle Stroke="#570000FF" StrokeThickness="10"/>
    </Border>

</StackPanel>
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Maybe it's the same thing but in my example, the black line is the same in all of the examples, and the blue is the border. Is it the same principle? I am very new to WPF so it could be a stupid question... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sipo what are you using as a basis of comparison? Each of your examples has 2 borders effectively since the thin line and the thick line wouldn't be the same in anything I've encountered unless maybe for example making an Outline Path in Adobe Illustrator. As example, if you did the css equivalent of `border: blue 10px solid;` you couldn't expect a thin black line anywhere either.

Comment: After trying your examples - I managed to use them for my purpose. Thank a lot!

Also, the idea comes from the Stroke effect inside the blending options of a layer in Adobe Photoshop. :)