# How to outline data grid cells from the inside so the data grid rows are not shifted?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, styling

Basically I am outlining the selected row entirely. But the issue is when I select a row, I can see it slightly moving down the rows that come after it.

How can I prevent this? Do I have to draw an outline from the inside so that the row is not resized?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void SetField<T> ( ref T field, T value, string propertyName )
        {
            if ( !EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals ( field, value ) )
            {
                field = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke ( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs ( propertyName ) );
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Coin> _coins;
        public ObservableCollection<Coin> Coins { get => _coins; set => SetField ( ref _coins, value, nameof ( _coins ) ); }
        public ICollectionView CollectionView;

        public MainWindow ( )
        {
            this.Coins = new ObservableCollection<Coin> ( );
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 40 ; ++i )
                this.Coins.Add ( new Coin ( "Coin 1", i ) );

            this.DataContext = this;

            InitializeComponent ( );
        }
    }

    public class Coin
    {
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public int PNL { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush Color2 { get; set; }

        public Coin ( string symbol, int pnl )
        {
            this.Symbol = symbol;
            this.PNL = pnl;

            Random rnd = new Random ( );
            Color c = Color.FromRgb ( ( byte ) rnd.Next ( 256 ), ( byte ) rnd.Next ( 256 ), ( byte ) rnd.Next ( 256 ) );

            this.Color2 = new SolidColorBrush ( c );
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="myMainWindow"
    SizeToContent="Width"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="Profit Tracker"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Topmost="True"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Height="426">

    <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#1e90ff"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnAlarmStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#000000"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF" />
            <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="RowStyleWithAlternation" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#282828"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,0,0" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#1e90ff" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>-->
                </Trigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value=" "/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Symbol"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="PNL %"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Color2}" />
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="12"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="13"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeDailyBackColor}" />
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeDailyForeColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="14"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyBackColor}" />
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyForeColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Min %"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeMinutelyForeColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Net BTC/m"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=LastMinuteVolumeColor}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#006400" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#75001D" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Coins}" IsLiveSortingRequested="True" x:Key="MyKey" />

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyKey}}" SelectionMode="Single" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyleWithAlternation}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PNL" Width="60" SortMemberPath="Balance.UnitPrice" Binding="{Binding Path=PNL}" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}" CanUserSort="False"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Vol BTC/h" Width="30" SortMemberPath="LastHourVolumeInBtc">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="ABCDE" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Vol BTC/h" Width="40">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <ProgressBar Value="0.3" Minimum="0" Maximum="1"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="12345" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Net BTC/m" Width="60"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This example is a bit verbose. It would be easier if you provided only a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

Workaround

One possibility is to change the **RowStyleWithAlternation** style.
I have set the BorderThickness to 2 for test

```
   <Style x:Key="RowStyleWithAlternation" TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <!-- added line-->
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
                <!-- added line-->
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#141414" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#282828"/>
                <!-- added line-->
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#282828" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                <!--deleted lines-->
                <!--<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,0,0" />-->
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks when I do this, it breaks the continuity of the blur separator lines, and creates bigger gap between progress bars, etc. In the actual code I managed to close the gap of these too even for the progress bars, but if I use this method then there will be more gaps between rows.

Answer (score -2):

As seen in the answer to this question:
[In WPF, how to set an outer, centered, and inner border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480867/in-wpf-how-to-set-an-outer-centered-and-inner-border)

You draw a rectangle with a color that matches the background. Then you change the color of said rectangle on selection. This way the box size won't change. The internal border is always there it's just not always visible.